# Как удалить ImageMagick-last-libs ?

Tags: centos

надо удалить ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.i686. перепробовал и в ручную файлы удалить и

```
 # yum remove ImageMagick
```

но удалить все равно не получается. Подскажите как? Centos 6.5

Comment: какая ошибка?

Comment: нет никакой ошибки.просто это все удаляет пакет ImageMagick а не libs

Answer (score 1):

## yum erase ImageMagick-last-libs